# Drag and drop cancel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a Form with 2 Panels:
Panel1.BackColor is Color.Red
Panel2.BackColor is Color.Blue

When dragging panel1 to panel2, panel2 must take the color of panel1
When starting the drag operation panel1 must change color to white
When drag and drop is completed panel1 must return to color red.

All this is accomplished, but I still miss this:
if the drag and drop operation is cancelled (used dropping on other control, hitting ESC etc.) then the color of panel2 remains white, it does not revert to Color.Red.

How do I accomplish this?

I have tried to look at QueryContinueDrag, but can't seem to find a solution.

This is the code I have:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private dragBoxFromMouseDown As Rectangle

    Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
        Dim dragSize As Size = SystemInformation.DragSize
        dragBoxFromMouseDown = New Rectangle(New Point(e.X - (dragSize.Width / 2), e.Y - (dragSize.Height / 2)), dragSize)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseMove
        If ((e.Button And MouseButtons.Left) = MouseButtons.Left) Then
            If (Rectangle.op_Inequality(dragBoxFromMouseDown, Rectangle.Empty) And Not dragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.X, e.Y)) Then
                Panel1.BackColor = Color.White
                Panel1.DoDragDrop(sender.name, DragDropEffects.All)

            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel2_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Panel2.DragEnter
        If e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).contains("Panel1") Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel2_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Panel2.DragDrop
        Panel2.BackColor = Me.Controls(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)).backcolor
        Me.Controls(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)).backcolor = Color.Red
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you should handle the [QueryContinueDrag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.querycontinuedrag) event of the source Panel, to determine what action is being performed. It could be `Continue`, `Drop` or `Cancel`.
You want to restore the background color of the source Control when the current action is `DragAction.Drop` or `DragAction.Cancel`.

I've refactored some of the code presented here, because it contains some weird stuff.
For example, you can simply pass the Control instance to the `DoDragDrop()` method, then verify with `e.Data.GetDataPresent()` that it contains the Type you want to handle.
Also, some null checks are missing

```
Private panelQueryDragPosition As Point
Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
    panelQueryDragPosition = e.Location
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left AndAlso
        (Math.Abs(e.X - panelQueryDragPosition.X) > SystemInformation.DragSize.Width OrElse
         Math.Abs(e.Y - panelQueryDragPosition.Y) > SystemInformation.DragSize.Height) Then
        Dim ctl = DirectCast(sender, Panel)  ' The source Control cannot be null here
        ctl.BackColor = Color.White
        ctl.DoDragDrop(ctl, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_QueryContinueDrag(sender As Object, e As QueryContinueDragEventArgs) Handles Panel1.QueryContinueDrag
    If e.Action = DragAction.Drop OrElse e.Action = DragAction.Cancel Then
        Dim ctl = DirectCast(sender, Control)
        If ctl IsNot Nothing Then ctl.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Panel2_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Panel2.DragEnter
    If e.Data IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(Panel)) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Panel2_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Panel2.DragDrop
    Dim panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)
    If panel IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Data IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(Panel)) Then
        Dim sourceControl = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(GetType(Panel)), Panel)
        panel.BackColor = sourceControl.BackColor
    End If
End Sub
```